# Group by object value in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I need to display data grouped by some categories. The thing is that the name of the category is one the values from the query and is not an object key.

This is the query:

```
getTools() {
return this.adalSrv.get(
  environment.endpoints_sharepoint,
  environment.endpoints_sharepoint
  + environment.environment_sharepoint_extension + '/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle(\'Herramientas\')/items?$filter=(Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Herramienta eq \'Web\')&$select=ID,Configuracion,Descripcion,Title,URLEnlace,CategoriaHerr/Title&$expand=CategoriaHerr/Title'
).map(tools => tools.d.results.map(item => {
  return new Object({
    id: item.Id,
    title: item.Title,
    desc: item.Descripcion,
    cat: item.CategoriaHerr.Title,
    link: item.URLEnlace,
    src: {
      path: JSON.parse(item.Configuracion).IconoHer.path,
      fichero: JSON.parse(item.Configuracion).IconoHer.fichero
      },
    str1: item.Title.charAt(0),
    str2: item.Title.charAt(1),
  });
}));
}
```

This is what i receive when i subscribe: 
[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnKi8.png)

And i need to display it like this:

```
<div class="tools-category">
  <h3>{{cat}}</h3>
  <div class="tools-by-cat">
  <div *ngFor="let tool of tools" class="tool-item"><p>{{nameTool}}</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I mean, all tools grouped by category in different divs.

I'm trying to do an ngFor inside another ngFor...but getting lots of empty divs.

Comment: Can you add some code from your component?
You could check on <p> if 'nameTool' is empty. 

Btw, your tool-item is out of your " " :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Your css class is outside of the quotes
2. Your are not accessing the value of the loop correctly

Check if the following code fixes your problem. If not, adjust your question with some more code of your components (preferably in a working [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com)) and I'll update my answer accordingly:

```
<h3>{{cat}}</h3>
<div class="tools-by-cat">
  <div *ngFor="let tool of tools" class="tool-item"><p>{{tool.cat}}</p></div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

AFAIK angular currently doesn't support grouping out of the box, but there is a package called [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#groupby) which you can use.

First install `ngx-pipes`: `npm install ngx-pipes --save` and add it to your module

```
import {NgPipesModule} from 'ngx-pipes';

@NgModule({
 // ...
 imports: [
   // ...
   NgPipesModule
 ]
})
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<div class="tools-category" *ngFor="let tool of tools | groupBy:'cat' | pairs ">
    <h3>{{tool[0]}}</h3>
    <div class="tools-by-cat">
        <div *ngFor="let val of tool[1]" class="tool-item">
            <h2>{{val.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{val.desc}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `tools` is your list of objects.

Here is a working [stackblitz groupBy example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-groupby). I simplified your data because you didn't provide it as code to copy&paste (in the future you should copy&paste log results instead of posting an image).

Comment: Sorry about the quotes, i wrote it wrong. The thing that i need is to group all tools by category.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina I've adjusted my answer and added a working example with grouping. Please check and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @coreuter ! now its working! But im trying to put a component inside ".tool-item" that contains a img for every tool, but im having this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null"; All images are showing but i think its trying to call much more images.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina Since this a new problem it would be best to create a new question. You can fork my stackblitz and add your image component and everything else you modified in the meantime. That way it's easier for others to look for the problem. Since your original question is answered, please [close your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @coreuter, you code can improve at the following:

- it's unadvised to create Objects in a loop, so I would move the `new Object()` outside of the loop.
- In other hand, as you described your problem it seams you don't really need the `new Object()` method, since you're only mapping values.

If I understood you correctly, you expect the following:
**input**

`[
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Seg...."},
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Senda...."},
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Herr Cola" }, Title: "Herr"}
]`

**desired output**

`[
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Seg...."},
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Senda...."}
]
{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Herr Cola" }, Title: "Herr"}
]`

You can approach this with lodash (or similar functional programing library) like this:
**Sample**

`_.groupBy([{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Seg...."},{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Administrative Tools" }, Title: "Senda...."},{ CategoriaHerr: { Title: "Herr Cola" }, Title: "Herr"}], 'CategoriaHerr.Title')`

**Your code**

`getTools() {
return this.adalSrv.get(
  environment.endpoints_sharepoint,
  environment.endpoints_sharepoint
  + environment.environment_sharepoint_extension + '/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle(\'Herramientas\')/items?$filter=(Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Herramienta eq \'Web\')&$select=ID,Configuracion,Descripcion,Title,URLEnlace,CategoriaHerr/Title&$expand=CategoriaHerr/Title'
).map(tools => ( _.groupBy(tools.d.results, 'CategoriaHerr.Title' )`

**Your HTML**
```

#### {{cat}}

### {{cat.key}}

{{item.title}}

`**Get keys pipe**`

    import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({name: 'getValues'})
export class GetValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(map: Map<any, any>): any[] {
        let ret = [];

        map.forEach((val, key) => {
            ret.push({
                key: key,
                val: val
            });
        });

        return ret;
    }
}
```

```

Hope it helps.